# How to populate new rows with specific data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

In Microsoft Excel, I have User and Product data stored in a sheet. I may add/remove New User or New Product in this sheet.

I have another sheet, which has to put all products to each Users. I need a formula to put them in, like in the example below: every time I add/remove user or product.

Example:

[image: sample]

Comment: so your table shared is the output?.. or the input.. ?

Comment: left side user and product datas are input
right side is the output. product numbers are put for every each User.

Comment: Man, you have used 2 separate tags - Excel and Google sheets. Which of them do you actually work with?

Comment: Sorry it will be for Excel.

Comment: While a bit more work to set up intially and requires a bit of programming, this is more a database application. You then can have a table of users and table of products and a table of the join between them. Years ago I used dBase II as spread sheets were very limited. Then converted to MS Access.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the "USER 1" is located in cell A2, put this in B2 then drag downwards :

```
="PRODUCT "&COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)
```

Idea : concatenate text with a moving countif().

Please share if it works/not/understandable. ( :

================

Upon comments & follow up, here is the revised solution. With the sample file shared by the OP, in Output sheet, just put these formula..

in cell A2 :

```
=IF((ROW()-1)>((COUNTA(Input!B:B)-1)*(COUNTA(Input!A:A)-2)),"",INDEX(Input!A:A,1+ INT((ROW()-2)/(COUNTA(Input!B:B)-1))+2))
```

in cell B2 :

```
=IF((ROW()-1)>((COUNTA(Input!B:B)-1)*(COUNTA(Input!A:A)-2)),"",INDEX(Input!B:B,COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)+2))
```

and drag downwards.

Idea :

1. count how many rows are not empty in column A & B of input sheet.
2. use math manipulation of row() with the above count.. to 'load' items in column A/B into output sheet
3. stop giving output if the row() number is exceeding (number of rows that are not empty in column B )*(number of rows that are not empty in column B )

Within the formula, it is...

1. --> `COUNTA(Input!B:B) & COUNTA(Input!A:A)`
2. ---> `INDEX(Input!B:B,COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)+2)`
3. ---> `IF((ROW()-1)>((COUNTA(Input!B:B)-1)*(COUNTA(Input!A:A)-2)),"", ... )`

Hope it helps. ( :

Comment: Thanks but names won't be product :) They will be different names from each other.

Comment: any example of the data from the other sheet? | hint : you can explore excel "index match" method and 'load' the value using countif().

Comment: Input is the left side and the output (other sheet) is right side. can you please check from the sample uploaded pic?

Comment: you may share a sample file/data to further assist.. | here is the index match [link](https://exceljet.net/index-and-match) should you want to have a try.. ( :

Comment: how can i share the example sheet on here?

Comment: share it in google drive > share link ( and test the link before sharing it here...)

Comment: here it is: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1seNbUDi4rP8YaUzhZjkn5ACG5yDDrmHM64CX84pQBKk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: so if you have 3 users & 3 products.. the full output will be a list of 9 user-product pair.. right?

Comment: @HakanErdur,, considering shared data (Google Sheet), you have standard format (data set),, in another words each user has common products (25) and if U add or remove product, total number of products will be similar for every user since Input range  is identical for every user,,, therefore creating output will be like replicating the job (products for users). My suggestion is [Edit] the post and be specific about your need and avoid vote to close the post !!

Comment: Dear Hakan.. how does it goes ?